# How to handle multiple gradle projects and dependencies within intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have two (CORE and WEB) gradle projects, each within its own repository.

- CORE builds a JAR file (that is published to your inhouse artifactory)
- WEB has a compile dependency to that JAR

Is it possible that, during development, the WEB projects uses the local CORE code?

I tried to make a workspace containing both projects (as modules) but the WEB projects does not use the local CORE jar, instead it fetches from the artifactory.

The current folder structure, I tried:

```
./core/
./core/build.gradle
./core/settings.gradle
./web/
./web/build.gradle
./web/settings.gradle
```

**./core/settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'core'
```

**./web/settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'web'
```

**./web/build.gradle**

```
...
dependencies {
  compile 'com.me.core' // this is the CORE depdendency
}
```

Currently, I need to change something in CORE, commit and push it into git, wait for the build pipeline to finish and publish the artifact and then fetch the new artifact within WEB from the artifactory.

*EDIT: I also took a look at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html but couldn't get it work.*

I do not want to have a single repository with respective root and sub-projects.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have them in separate repos, what you can do is:

1. Build a jar of `core` locally (let's say `core.jar`)
2. Copy it to the `web` project under a directory (e.g. `libs`). You can automate this step with a [gradle `Copy` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files) on every build.
3. Set this local dependency in `./web/build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
   }
}


dependencies {
   implementation name: 'core'
}
```

However, this is a very common use case for multi-project builds. Check the example on the gradle documentation: [Project Jar Dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies). But for this you'll have to have them both in one repo.